# Kentico dynamic content

Tags: dynamic, asp-classic, content-management-system, kentico

Context:
Using kentico 5.5 R2.
We have 6 product types (workshops, under those types there are several workshops which are unique by date and location). They each share the same registration process but on the last step the content changes depending on the product chosen. In the CMS they share the first 2 steps of the registration and they are pages, the last page is a blank page, and the unique content pieces are sub pages in a folder.

Somehow the devs loaded the dynamic content in the final page (called Register-Step-Done), and I can't seem to find any logic or anything in the CMS that makes this work. i.e. something that says Product Type A uses Content A.

We are trying to add a 7th product type, I've added the unique content piece just like the others (as a sub page in the same folder with the same naming convention), but when it hits the final step for this new 7th product it's just blank (Register-Step-Done) and not loading that unique content in.

Comment: Can you see any custom handlers in you solution? They might be a separate projects in the solution compiled to dlls and added to Kentico bin folder

Comment: @RomanHutnyk They use custom web parts for the whole registration process. Looking through the custom asp file for Register-Step-Done I don't see anything that loads the custom content, although I don't know enough about kentico or ASP to tell for sure.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not provide enough info (at least for me) that I can advice you something... Is this a Kentico portal page or aspx page? Are there any other web parts or widgets on it?

Comment: hey @RomanHutnyk I totally understand and I thank you for trying. I'm not sure how much I can share and if I can post any code snippets. It's a portal page that has the 1 web part, which is an aspx page on the server. The page does a few things like checks if it is a product that is purchasable and sends the item to a cart, things like that, but that's all working well right now, just the piece where it's loading content from another page depending on product (workshop) type.

Answer (score 1):

Well turns out the original devs put a custom case statement in a file in \App_Code\Util\ and hardcoded some CMS page names to get it all working.... Very frustrating experience.